# Why HashSet<T> does not implement IReadOnlyCollection<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, .net-4.5

I've just found that .NET Fx now has 3 useful interfaces:

1. [`IReadOnlyCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh881542)
2. [`IReadOnlyList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192385)
3. [`IReadOnlyDictionary<K,V>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh136548)

And I'm bit confused why [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110)) do not implement `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`? Are there any reasons, or Microsoft just forgot about sets again?

**UPD**

After two-hours googling I've found that there are many collections in BCL which has `.Count` property but do not implement `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` interface.

**UPD2**

I've found this post http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/b4fb991a-3f5c-4923-93d4-7cd5c004f859 and the answer by *Immo Landwerth* where he've said following

> **Will other collections besides List<> and Dictionary<> be updated to
>   support these interfaces?**
>
> Absolutely. In fact, all of our built-in collection types already
>   implement IReadOnlyList<> and IReadOnlyDictionary<>. This means, you
>   can directly pass an instance of List, T[] or Dictionary<> to an
>   API that takes an IReadOnly-version of it.

Comment: Ok, so why [List<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110)) does?

Comment: Weird. Imho, an incongruent design decision. See http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/10/ReadOnly-WInRT/

Comment: @ColonelPanic You misunderstand the intention of `IReadOnlyCollection<>`. Most mutable collections implement this interface. The cool thing about it is that it's **covariant**. Therefore, if you know you're going to only **read** from a collection that goes into a method, you can make the method take an `IReadOnlyCollection<Animal>`. If someone has a `List<Giraffe>`, they can use it as input to your method because of covariance. That's really cool!

Comment: Makes sense, cool. So the answer to the OP's question is 'Yes ISet should implement IReadOnlyCollection, this appears to be an oversight by devs'

Comment: Update 2015: Fixed in .NET 4.6

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen It would be cool if the interface was named `IReadableCollection`. It's not cool to name something in a way that is completely illogical given how it's used.

Comment: @jpmc26 I agree there is some confusing naming here. If you have a `List<>` instance and you say `.AsReadOnly()` on it, you get a _wrapper_ around your list that will not let you modify the list (others could modify it, so it is not truly immutable). That wrapper class is called `ReadOnlyCollection<>`. So "read-only" is used in another sense there. I kind of like your `IReadableCollection<>` idea. However, it is much too late to fix the confusing names now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In version 4.5 of the framework, [`HashSet<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) does not implement `IReadOnlyCollection<out T>`.

This omission was resolved in version 4.6 of the framework (released almost 12 months after the above question was asked).

These corrections are [not limited to `HashSet<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868(v=vs.110).aspx), other collections such as [`Stack<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Queue<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c(v=vs.110).aspx) have received these improvements.

Speculation on the reason for any omission is moot. It may be oversight or time pressure but frankly, it is of little consequence. I suspect that even direct input from the Microsoft Development Team would be somewhat subjective, even if we enjoy associated anecdotes.