# Cannot convert HashSet to IReadOnlyCollection

Tags: c#, .net

I have a HashSet and I am trying to cast it into IReadOnlyCollection, but I am getting error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Hashset is a

```
public class HashSet<T> : ICollection<T>, ISerializable, IDeserializationCallback, ISet<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>
```

I can use explicit cast, but I don't know the reason why I can't just use it as IReadOnlyCollection.

```
HashSet<DateTime> set = new HashSet<DateTime> { DateTime.Today };
ICollection<DateTime> collection = set; // OK
ISerializable serializable = set;       // OK
IDeserializationCallback deserializationCallback = set; // OK
ISet<DateTime> iSet = set;                              // OK
IReadOnlyCollection<DateTime> castReadOnlyCollection = (IReadOnlyCollection<DateTime>)set; // OK
IReadOnlyCollection<DateTime> readOnlyCollection = set; // Error
```

Why can't I use it without an explicit cast?

I am using .NET framework 4.5

Comment: And apparently it did not always implement that interface http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849861/why-hashsett-does-not-implement-ireadonlycollectiont

Comment: It was an oops in .NET 4.5, induced by IReadOnlyCollection<> being added to support the WinRT language projection and WinRT not having an equivalent of a set.  It got fixed in 4.5.1, simply change your project's framework target as a workaround.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You're using 4.5 and Hashset doesn't implement IReadOnlyCollection until 4.6

From MSDN:

> HashSet implements the IReadOnlyCollection interface starting with the .NET Framework 4.6; in previous versions of the .NET Framework, the HashSet class did not implement this interface.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: At the top of the page it says ".NET Framework 4.6 and 4.5", so I didn't expect changes in API. That is not the case, good to know. Thanks.

Comment: Thus is the world of documentation. Some are better than others but all will inevitably have their inaccuracies, unfortunately.

Answer (score 12):

This is because in .NET 4.5, `HashSet<T>` doesn't implement `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`. In .NET 4.6, it does, so the implicit cast works as expected.

BTW, the explicit cast in your code snippet compiles, but it will fail at runtime. It compiles because the `set` variable is of type `HashSet<DateTime>`, and since `HashSet<DateTime>` is not sealed, there might be subclasses that implement the interface.

Comment: Thanks, I have probably another weird issue there. Project says Framework 4.5, but R# test with cast succeeds (unit tests should use target platform of a project).