# implicit/explicit cast confusion on IReadOnlyCollection

Tags: c#, visual-studio, type-conversion, .net-4.5, readonly-collection

Why are different collections (that all implement the `IReadOnlyCollection` interface) handled differently by the compiler when trying to turn them into `IReadOnlyCollection`?

```
IReadOnlyCollection<int> a = new List<int>();       // everything fine
IReadOnlyCollection<int> b = new HashSet<int>();    // compiler wants me to cast
IReadOnlyCollection<int> c = new Stack<int>();      // compiler wants me to cast
IReadOnlyCollection<int> d = new Queue<int>();      // compiler wants me to cast
IReadOnlyCollection<int> e = new LinkedList<int>(); // compiler wants me to cast
IReadOnlyCollection<int> f = new SortedSet<int>();  // compiler wants me to cast
```

I'm using .NET 4.5 and VisualStudio 2015.

The compiler error in the above cases is this:

Type `Queue<int>`/`Stack<int>`/... cannot be implicitly converted into `IReadOnlyCollection<int>`. An explicit conversion exists. Are you missing a cast?

(This is not the actual text, but I believe you wouldn't want me to copy-paste a German text here.)

If I do the cast by

```
IReadOnlyCollection<int> d = new Queue<int>() as IReadOnlyCollection<int>;
```

or even by

```
IReadOnlyCollection<int> d = (IReadOnlyCollection<int>)new Queue<int>();
```

everything is fine; it gives me no compilation or run-time errors.

Comment: IReadOnlyCollection exists since .NET 4.5 as far as I know.

Comment: `List` is a general class; but for example `LinkedList` is a sub-class for the List class. It may be about inheritance issue, but I want to learn that answer, too.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this either - perhaps as one clue to us, can you tell us what, specifically, the compiler says as an error or warning?

Comment: @J.Steen do you have any idea which other options besides the .NET version to use could influence the compiler behaviour?

Comment: Just to be sure, it's the Compiler, not the Resharper?

Comment: I don't have Resharper installed, so I guess it must be the compiler.

Comment: I think it's just vanilla .NET. I have added some libraries, but I am not using them in the above code.

Comment: It runs and behaves as expected. That means, I could write `IReadOnlyCollection<int> d = (IReadOnlyCollection<int>)new Queue<int>();` and do not get any runtime exception.

Comment: Mb it's work so because there was no direct conversion at Net 4.5 done for  those collections?

Comment: @J.Steen - I get the same error when I try this even targeting 4.5.2

Comment: @J.Steen VS 2015, standard console application. If I target 4.6 however, the error disappears.

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32762631/cannot-convert-hashset-to-ireadonlycollection/32762752#32762752

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you target .NET 4.6 or above this does compile.

At this version `SortedSet` (for example) does implement the `IReadOnlyCollection` (checked by right clicking and selecting "Go To Definition).

The full list is:

> ISet<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable, ICollection, ISerializable, IDeserializationCallback, IReadOnlyCollection<T>

at 4.5 it only implements:

> ISet<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, ICollection, IEnumerable, ISerializable, IDeserializationCallback

If the documentation says otherwise, then (I'm afraid) the documentation is wrong.